# WCF endpoint binding for SOAP 1.1

Tags: wcf, soap, binding

I am consuming a third party Soap service in a .NET application and I keep getting this error -

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).

I checked the configuration.svcinfo and the binding seems to be basicHttpBinding. From the soap response it appears to be Soap 1.1. I am able to get this response using a downloaded Soap client but when called from .NET application, I get this error. I have checked many articles and some of them pointed to issues related to Soap 1.2 which I don't think is the case here. The endpoint configuration matches whats in the configuration.svcinfo

[image: Soap Response from third party service]